# How to return an object with strings with typescript using the map method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this part of code:

```
    var dependencies:any = npmPackage.versions[version].dependencies;

    dependencies = Object.entries(dependencies).map( ([name, version]) => {
        console.log(name,typeof(version));
        return {
            name,
            version.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''),
        }
    });
```

it should turn this:

```
{
    "loose-envify": "^1.1.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2"
}
```

to this:

```
[
    {
        name: "loose-envify", 
        version: "^1.1.0" 
    }, 
    {
        name: "object-assign", 
        version: "^4.1.1"
    }, 
    {
        same here...
    }
]
```

I am tring to remove the chars like `~ ! ^` from the version variable (instead `^4.1.1` => `4.1.1`), I keep getting the error:

> ',' expected.

for the `version.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''),` part.

I'm guessing it's due to the typescript. I don't think this should cause any problem.. when having the return version variable only as `version` it works without this error.
I'm kinda new to typescript so I'd be happy to understand why rather than just getting the answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code, with a slight modification to add a property name, works at runtime, so the problem is due to TypeScript. My advice: remove the TypeScript, or, use a new variable and type it correctly. I'll show the latter in a comment here:

```js
let dependencies = {
  "loose-envify": "^1.1.0",
  "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
  "prop-types": "^15.6.2"
};
const nameVersionDeps /* : { name: string; version: string; }[] */ = Object.entries(dependencies).map(([name, version]) => {
  return {
    name,
    version: version.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''),
  }
});
console.log(nameVersionDeps)
```

Comment: yes, I guess it's the `dependencies` variable type. what type is the variable when i do this: `npmPackage.versions[version].dependencies`? isn't that a string (following the interface type).so if I edit it later in another variable (in this case dependencies)`var dependencies = npmPackage.versions[version].dependencies` does it get the previous type from previous variable? does it asign a new one? should i asign a new one? (`:string` didn't do the job). there is that thing with typescript that i just cannot understand yet, and this is it. (i used `:any` just because it did the job in the past)

Comment: oh. removing typescript isn't an option in this case. I prefer to understand why this happens rather than burring it :)

Comment: `dependencies?: {
        [packageName: string]: string;
      };` is what I see. Which is an object with properties that hold strings, not a string. Which is not an array of objects with `name` and `version` properties. You can use `:any`, but you lose type safety and IntelliSense and all those goodies. Basically, that's what I mean when I say "don't use TypeScript" because `any` is just saying "I give up" :).

Comment: it sure is.. just wanted to handle it in the end.. but its not the case for me unfortunately.  I tried assigning a new type for `var dependencies` and it doesn't work. so do i understand correctly? when i assign a new variable to a sub-sub-object - it keeps the type too? (`{ [packageName: string]: string; }` - what is the common typescript solution for this kind of situation? I deffinetly want to code properly. there are some concepts that i just could not get from a basic type tutorial :(

Comment: Yeah, it keeps the type. Typically, one has multiple types. For instance, you'd have a type for what you are receiving (a so-called DTO, or data transfer object), which describes the shape of what you're getting). Then you might have a type for what your app uses internally that might be a transformation of what you're getting (in your case, the changed `dependencies` type). Then you might have a type for what your app displays (sometimes certain components need a particular shape of data). It can get to be a lot of types, but *usually* it's worth knowing things are where you expect it to be.

Comment: great so I learned the theoretical part thanks to you! :)  lets say I work in a company that uses typescript and this is the case: I have a result from a "typed" variable - which I want to change and return - with a different "shape". what is the common practice which is considered "good practice"? should I edit the current type of variable and change the whole interface thing (is it even possible in my case here?)? can I assign a new type only for the new variable I want to return?

Comment: You would need to define a new type for the return value. You wouldn't be able to change the existing interface, because presumably you have data that's in that format, and it would fail if it was given the invalid interface. But we're getting off the subject of this particular question and answer, and I have paid work to do :). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a property name :

```
return {
       name,
       version : version.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''), // <-- here a property name required
}
```

And the error you are getting is not related to typescript. Here javascript can't determine the property name (like most of the languages that provide similar functionality.) because of a function call. It should be a variable.
The feature you use is called object property value shorthand. Here some examples :

```
const foo = 1 ;
const bar = {c: "baz"};
const shortHand = { foo,bar}; // foo and bar property names
const fail = { foo,bar.c}; // here property name can't be infered.

const fail2 = {bar, foo.toString()} // here property name can't be infered.
```

And for the regex I would suggest a pattern like :

```
/^[\^!~]/gi
```

Comment: `Object is type 'unknown'.` for `version.`

Comment: can you explain why it cannot determine the property name? whats the difference between having this line `version : version.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''),` to `version` (which works)

Comment: im not sure i understand :(

Comment: Using a variable only as an object key and value works if it's just that variable name, so `{ version }` is ok because it turns into `{ version: "whateverVersionEquals" }` but `{version.someOperation()}` does not follow that pattern and you need to use the full key/value syntax.

Comment: YES! got it! thanks. Any idea how to work around this situation? or what is recommended doing in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the trailing comma of your line here:
`version.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''),` and if you want to remove `~ ! ^` then use this regex: `/[~!^]/gi`

Comment: ah , i tried that too. its not the comma.

Comment: `{
    {
        name: "loose-envify", 
        version: "^1.1.0" 
    }, 
    {
        name: "object-assign", 
        version: "^4.1.1"
    }}` where did this code example come from as this is not a proper object?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but this code should do the conversion part:

```
startingObject = {
    "loose-envify": "^1.1.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2"
}

Object.entries(startingObject).map(entry => ({ name: entry[0], value: entry[1] }))
```

Will produce:

```
[
    {
        name: "loose-envify", 
        version: "^1.1.0" 
    }, 
    {
        name: "object-assign", 
        version: "^4.1.1"
    },
    {
        name: "prop-types", 
        version: "^15.6.2"
    }
]
```

Comment: almost. I'm trying to get rid of the ^ symbol in the "version:" part